# High precision numerical solution of the nonlinear Volterra integral equation

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations

Let consider nonlinear Volterra integral equation 5.1 from the paper [An iterative multistep kernel based method for nonlinear Volterra integral and integro-differential equations of fractional order](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377042719302031?via%20%253%20Dihub)
$$u(x)=x^2 (1+\cos x^2)/2+\int_0^x{sx^2}\sin u(s) ds$$ with exact solution $y=x^2$.
My question is about very precise numerical solution of this Volterra integral equations based on the algorithm discussed in the paper [A new numerical method for fractional order Volterra integro-differential equations.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2090447919301005?via%20%253%20Dihub) In the cited paper they proposed very precise numerical solutions for several equations (not mentioned above) with error of $10^{-18}$. My doubt is that how numerical solution getting with wavelets technic can be so precise?
Nevertheless studying equation 5.1 with Bernoulli wavelets I have
got precise numerical solution with error of $10^{-17}$ for 16 collocation points.
My algorithm is differ from that explained in the paper since I
can' t reproduce numerical method from this paper. Code :

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"]; \
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"]; ue[x_] := x^2; 
f[x_] := x^2 + x^2 (Cos[x^2] - 1)/2;
n = 3;
M = Sum[1, {j, 0, n, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 1; 
dx = 1/M; A = 0; xl = Table[A + l*dx, {l, 0, M}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, M + 1}]; 
psi1[x_] := Piecewise[{{BernoulliB[2, x], 0 <= x < 1}, {0, True}}]; 
psi2[x_] :=  Piecewise[{{BernoulliB[1, x], 0 <= x < 1}, {0, True}}]; 
psi1jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi1[j*x - k]; 
psi2jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi2[j*x - k]; 
psijk[x_, j_, k_] := (psi1jk[x, j, k] + psi2jk[x, j, k]);


 np =2 M; points = weights = Table[Null, {np}]; Do[
 points[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, -1, 1][[i, 1]], {i, 1, 
  np}];
Do[weights[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, -1, 1][[i, 2]], {i, 1,
    np}];
GuassInt[ff_, z_] := 
  Sum[(ff /. z -> points[[i]])*weights[[i]], {i, 1, np}];
u[t_] := Sum[
    a[j, k]*psijk[t, 2^j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + a0 ; 
int[x_] := (x/2)^2 x^2 GuassInt[(1 + z) Sin[u[x/2 (z + 1)]], 
    z](*s\[Rule]x/2 (1+z)*);
eq = Table[-u[xcol[[i]]] + f[xcol[[i]]] + int[xcol[[i]]] == 0, {i, 
    Length[xcol]}];
varM = Join[{a0}, 
   Flatten[Table[a[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]]; 
sol = FindRoot[eq, Table[{varM[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varM]}]];
unum = Table[ {xcol[[i]], Evaluate[u[xcol[[i]]] /. sol]}, {i, 
    Length[xcol]}];

 du = 
 Table[{x, Abs[ue[x] - Evaluate[u[x] /. sol]]}, {x, xcol}]

Out[]= {{1/32, 4.11997*10^-18}, {3/32, 2.77556*10^-17}, {5/32, 
  2.08167*10^-17}, {7/32, 1.38778*10^-17}, {9/32, 
  2.77556*10^-17}, {11/32, 1.38778*10^-17}, {13/32, 
  2.77556*10^-17}, {15/32, 2.77556*10^-17}, {17/32, 0.}, {19/32, 
  0.}, {21/32, 0.}, {23/32, 0.}, {25/32, 0.}, {27/32, 0.}, {29/32, 
  0.}, {31/32, 0.}}
```

Visualization

```
{Show[Plot[ue[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{"Exact"}, LabelStyle -> {Black, 15}], 
     Scaled[{0.2, 0.8}]], AspectRatio -> 1, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[{FontSize -> 15}, Black], 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "u"}, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
  ListPlot[unum, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[PointLegend[{"Numeric"}, LabelStyle -> {Black, 15}], 
     Scaled[{0.2, 0.9}]]]], 
 ListPlot[du, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"Number of collocation points =", M}]]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Update 1. Next example been published in A Method for Solving Nonlinear Volterra Integral
Equations of the Second Kind By Peter Linz. AMS 1968:
$$y(x)=1+x-\cos x-\int_0^x \cos (x-t)y(t)dt $$ with exact solution $y=x$. Next code gives numerical solution with absolute error of $10^{-16}$:

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"]; \
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"]; ue[x_] := x; 
f[x_] := 1 + x - Cos[x];
n = 3;
M = Sum[1, {j, 0, n, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 1; 
dx = 1/M; A = 0; xl = Table[A + l*dx, {l, 0, M}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, M + 1}]; 
psi2[x_] := Piecewise[{{BernoulliB[2, x], 0 <= x < 1}, {0, True}}]; 
psi1[x_] :=  Piecewise[{{BernoulliB[1, x], 0 <= x < 1}, {0, True}}]; 
psi1jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi1[j*x - k]; 
psi2jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi2[j*x - k]; 
psijk[x_, j_, k_] := 0 psi2jk[x, j, k] + 2 psi1jk[x, j, k];


np = 2 M; points = weights = Table[Null, {np}]; Do[
 points[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, -1, 1][[i, 1]], {i, 1, 
  np}];
Do[weights[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, -1, 1][[i, 2]], {i, 1,
    np}];
GuassInt[ff_, z_] := 
  Sum[(ff /. z -> points[[i]])*weights[[i]], {i, 1, np}];
u[t_] := Sum[
    a[j, k]*psijk[t, 2^j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + a0 ; 
int[x_] := 
  x/2 GuassInt[Cos[x - x/2 (z + 1)] u[x/2 (z + 1)], 
    z](*s\[Rule]x/2 (1+z)*);
eq = Table[-u[xcol[[i]]] + f[xcol[[i]]] - int[xcol[[i]]] == 0, {i, 
    Length[xcol]}];
varM = Join[{a0}, 
   Flatten[Table[a[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]]; 
sol = FindRoot[eq, Table[{varM[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varM]}]];
unum = Table[ {xcol[[i]], Evaluate[u[xcol[[i]]] /. sol]}, {i, 
    Length[xcol]}];

du = Table[{x, Abs[ue[x] - Evaluate[u[x] /. sol]]}, {x, xcol}]
```

[image: Figure 2]
Update 2. Third example I got from the paper [New algorithms for the numerical solution of nonlinear Fredholm and Volterra integral equations using Haar wavelets.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042712003536?via%20%253%20Dihub)
[image: Figure3]
My code solves this problem with absolute error of $10^{-16}$

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"]; \
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"]; ue[x_] := 2 - x^2; 
f[x_] := -x^2 - x/3 (2 Sqrt[2] - 1) + 2;
n = 3;
M = Sum[1, {j, 0, n, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 1; 
dx = 1/M; A = 0; xl = Table[A + l*dx, {l, 0, M}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, M + 1}]; 
psi1[x_] := Piecewise[{{BernoulliB[2, x], 0 <= x < 1}, {0, True}}]; 
psi2[x_] :=  Piecewise[{{BernoulliB[1, x], 0 <= x < 1}, {0, True}}]; 
psi1jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi1[j*x - k]; 
psi2jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi2[j*x - k]; 
psijk[x_, j_, k_] := (psi1jk[x, j, k] + psi2jk[x, j, k])/2;


np = 2 M; points = weights = Table[Null, {np}]; Do[
 points[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, -1, 1][[i, 1]], {i, 1, 
  np}];
Do[weights[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, -1, 1][[i, 2]], {i, 1,
    np}];
GuassInt[ff_, z_] := 
  Sum[(ff /. z -> points[[i]])*weights[[i]], {i, 1, np}];
u[t_] := Sum[
    a[j, k]*psijk[t, 2^j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + a0 ; 
int[x_] := 
  x/2 GuassInt[(z + 1)/2 Sqrt[u[1/2 (z + 1)]], z](*s\[Rule]x/2 (1+z)*);
eq = Table[-u[xcol[[i]]] + f[xcol[[i]]] + int[xcol[[i]]] == 0, {i, 
    Length[xcol]}];
varM = Join[{a0}, 
   Flatten[Table[a[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]]; 
sol = FindRoot[eq, Table[{varM[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varM]}]];
unum = Table[ {xcol[[i]], Evaluate[u[xcol[[i]]] /. sol]}, {i, 
    Length[xcol]}];
```

[image: Figure 4]

The question is what the numerical phenomenon we have here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code we can check `GaussianQuadratureWeights` and `FindRoot` for  potential errors. Let us evaluate

```
GaussianQuadratureError[2 M, (1 + z) Sin[u[x/2 (z + 1)]], -1, 1]
```

and we have answer for $u(x)=x^2$

```
-6.5402263142525195*^-105*
 Derivative[64][(1 + z)*Sin[(1/4)*x^2*(1 + z)^2]]
```

Since $-1\le z\le 1, 0\le x\le 1$ we can conclude that Gauss quadrature not increases errors. Now we use standard code from tutorial

```
monitoredFindRoot[args__] := Module[{s = 0, e = 0, j = 0},
  {FindRoot[args, StepMonitor :> s++, EvaluationMonitor :> e++, 
    Jacobian -> {Automatic, EvaluationMonitor :> j++}], "Steps" -> s, 
   "Evaluations" -> e, "Jacobian Evaluations" -> j}]
```

For Example 1 we have

```
monitoredFindRoot[eq, 
 Table[{varM[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varM]}]]

Out[]= {{a0 -> 0.333333, a[0, 0] -> 1., a[1, 0] -> 3.74797*10^-17, 
  a[1, 1] -> -7.20275*10^-17, a[2, 0] -> 6.83321*10^-18, 
  a[2, 1] -> 1.08881*10^-17, a[2, 2] -> 8.19199*10^-18, 
  a[2, 3] -> 4.18911*10^-17, a[3, 0] -> -4.21268*10^-17, 
  a[3, 1] -> -1.35343*10^-17, a[3, 2] -> 7.7729*10^-17, 
  a[3, 3] -> -4.5043*10^-18, a[3, 4] -> 1.64461*10^-17, 
  a[3, 5] -> -5.19234*10^-17, a[3, 6] -> -2.37885*10^-17, 
  a[3, 7] -> -5.36736*10^-18}, "Steps" -> 4, "Evaluations" -> 5, 
 "Jacobian Evaluations" -> 4}
```

With `a0 -> 1/3, a[0, 0] -> 1` we get `u[x]->x^2`, so it takes 4 steps only to get exact solution with absolute error of $2.77556*10^{-17}$. But if we make any small changes in the code, then we turn numerical solution to the bigger errors. For instance, if we change in the code Example 1 wavelets to

```
psi1[x_] := WaveletPsi[HaarWavelet[], x]; 
psi2[x_] := WaveletPhi[HaarWavelet[], x];
```

then all miracles evaporate and we gonna have very common and expected result
[image: Figure 1]

Form the other side, if we make small modification to improve the last code, then we get fantastic unexpected result - numerical solution with zero absolute error:

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"]; \
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"]; ue[x_] := 2 - x^2;
f[x_] := -x^2 - x/3 (2 Sqrt[2] - 1) + 2;
n = 3;
M = Sum[1, {j, 0, n, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 1;
dx = 1/M; A = 0; xl = Table[A + l*dx, {l, 0, M}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, M + 1}];
psi1[x_] := Piecewise[{{BernoulliB[2, x], 0 <= x < 1}, {0, True}}];
psi2[x_] := Piecewise[{{BernoulliB[1, x], 0 <= x < 1}, {0, True}}];
psi1jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi1[j*x - k];
psi2jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi2[j*x - k];
psijk[x_, j_, k_] := (psi1jk[x, j, k] + psi2jk[x, j, k])/2;


np = 2 M; points = weights = Table[Null, {np}]; Do[
 points[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, -1, 1, 60][[i, 1]], {i, 
  1, np}];
Do[weights[[i]] = 
   GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, -1, 1, 60][[i, 2]], {i, 1, np}];
GuassInt[ff_, z_] := 
  Sum[(ff /. z -> points[[i]])*weights[[i]], {i, 1, np}];
u[t_] := Sum[
    a[j, k]*psijk[t, 2^j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + a0;
int[x_] := 
  x/2 GuassInt[(z + 1)/2 Sqrt[u[1/2 (z + 1)]], z](*s\[Rule]x/2 (1+z)*);
eq = Table[-u[xcol[[i]]] + f[xcol[[i]]] + int[xcol[[i]]] == 0, {i, 
    Length[xcol]}];
varM = Join[{a0}, 
   Flatten[Table[a[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]];
sol = FindRoot[eq, Table[{varM[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varM]}], 
   WorkingPrecision -> 30];
unum = Table[{xcol[[i]], Evaluate[u[xcol[[i]]] /. sol]}, {i, 
    Length[xcol]}];

du = Table[{x, Abs[ue[x] - Evaluate[u[x] /. sol]]}, {x, xcol}]

(*Out[]= {{1/32, 0.*10^-30}, {3/32, 0.*10^-30}, {5/32, 0.*10^-30}, {7/
  32, 0.*10^-30}, {9/32, 0.*10^-30}, {11/32, 0.*10^-30}, {13/32, 
  0.*10^-30}, {15/32, 0.*10^-30}, {17/32, 0.*10^-30}, {19/32, 
  0.*10^-30}, {21/32, 0.*10^-30}, {23/32, 0.*10^-30}, {25/32, 
  0.*10^-30}, {27/32, 0.*10^-30}, {29/32, 0.*10^-30}, {31/32, 
  0.*10^-30}}*}
```

[image: Figure 2]