# Issues with convergence of an iteration of numerical integrals computed with NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, iteration

This is my first question on Stack-Exchange. I am not an expert in numerical integration and I am having issues of convergence with some numerical integration. I am trying to solve numerically a nonlinear integral equation of which I know an exact solution. I want to compare my numerical results with the exact one (to check the correctness of the code). Unfortunately, after two iterations the numerical result starts departing from the exact behavior.

The integral equation to solve is:

$\qquad y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx G(t-x) [y(x)^2-1]y(x)$,

where

$\qquad G(t-x) = (1/2) (t - x)\, {\rm sign}(t - x).$

An analytic solution is given by

$\qquad y(x)=\tanh(x/\sqrt{2})$

The code I am using is the following:

```
t1 = -10;
t2 = 10;
n = 100;
m = 5;
t = Range[t1, t2, (t2 - t1)/(n)];
Do[
  y[x_, 0] = Tanh[x/Sqrt[2]];
  list[j] = 
    {t, 
      NIntegrate[
        (1/2)(t - x) Sign[t-x](y[x, j - 1]^2 - 1) y[x, j-1], {x, -10, 10}, 
        AccuracyGoal -> 13, WorkingPrecision -> 13]} // Transpose;
    sol[j] = Interpolation[list[j], Method -> "Spline"];
    y[x_, j] = sol[j][x], 
  {j, m}]
```

Basically, I am trivially starting from the exact solution for `j = 0`, and check the convergence at higher order in the iteration (I am doing this to verify whether the code is correct). But from `j = 3` the numerical solution starts departing from the exact one; so I would like to find a way to correct my code and make the iteration convergent for any higher `j`, as it should be.

I hope I have clearly stated my problem.

Comment: I don't know much about Green's Function, but doesn't it require a linear differential operator?

Comment: Hi Josh. Basically, given the equation y''(t)=F[y(t)], we can always formally write the solution as an integral of G(t-t') * F[y(t')], where G is the green function defined as the solution of the differential equation with a Dirac delta source. But I am not able to get numerically a convergent solution for that integral, whose exact solution is known. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you try to develop a new method of solution of  nonlinear Fredholm integral equations. Have you any theorem for this solution convergence?

Comment: `GreenFunction` is only defined for linear ode and gives a method to calculate one solution for general inhomogeneity in integral form. I don't see these requirements in your problem!

Comment: @user92 If I now understand you right you're looking for an iterative solution of the integralequation? If yes, starting the iteration with the known exact solution evaluates to `True` , that means the iteration will stop.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: Yes, this is what I am looking for. I want to find numerically the exact solution, and I was trivially starting directly with the exact solution to see how the iteration behaves. Do you think I shall start with a different function and see whether it converges to the exact one, in order to check whether the iteration really converges?

Comment: @user92 Yes, find a "good" starting function and start iteration with `NestList`

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but an attempt to derive the correct `GreenFunction` and the equivalent  integralequation using greens method.

The basic idea of @user92 is the (mis)use of greenfunction for a nonlinear ode.

`Greenfunction`  for the linear ode `y''[x]==f[x]` is given by

```
g[x_, \[Xi]_] := (x - \[Xi]) HeavisideTheta[x - \[Xi]]
```

**!!!Attention, @user92 gave another possible wrong formula!!!**

A possible solution of the linear ode `y''[x]==f[x]` can be expressed as `y[x]=Integrate[(x - \[Xi]) f[\[Xi]], {\[Xi], -Infinity, x}]`

```
D[Integrate[(x - \[Xi]) f[\[Xi]], {\[Xi], -Infinity, x}], {x, 2}]
(*f[x]*)
```

If this intergal holds for arbitrary `f[x]` it's valid to substitude the right hand side of the nonlinear ode `y''[x]== (y[x]^2-1)y[x]`

This gives the integral equation

`Integrate[(x - \[Xi]) (y[\[Xi]]^2 - 1) y[\[Xi]],{\[Xi], -Infinity,x}] == y[x]`

The given exact solution `y[x]=Tanh[x/Sqrt[2]]` isn't causal and fullfills the modified integralequation `Integrate[(x - \[Xi]) (y[\[Xi]]^2 - 1) y[\[Xi]],{\[Xi], -Infinity,x}]-1 == y[x]`

```
Y = -1 + Integrate[(x - \[Xi]) (y[\[Xi]]^2 - 1) y[\[Xi]], {\[Xi], -Infinity, x}] /.y -> ( Tanh[#/Sqrt[2]] &) // Simplify
Plot[{Y , Tanh[x/Sqrt[2]]}, {x, -5, 5},PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.01], Dashed}]
```

[image]

An iterative solution of the integralequation might be found using `NestList`

Comment: Since in your nonlinear Volterra integral equation $f=-1$, it is why numerical solution converses to $\tanh(x/\sqrt{2})$ not to $y=0$.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yes agreed, but it's not so easy to find a starting function for the iteration!

Comment: The starting function it is also a reason why people prefer collocation method.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  But the method needs correct(!)  integralequation, developped from the given nonlinear ode,  to work and give the right solution!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: Many thanks for your answer. I think that the way I wrote the question was a bit confusing, so I edited it trying to make it less confusing. With Green function I just meant the kernel of the integral equation, but I agree that it was a bit confusing. I now hope that my problem is clearly stated.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common problem for iterative method of solution of integral equations that numerical error decreases in the few first iteration and then increases. In this sense we prefer standard collocation method like described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226421/high-precision-numerical-solution-of-the-nonlinear-volterra-integral-equation). For example, we have nonlinear Fredholm integral equation
$$u(x)=f(x)+\int_0^1G(t,x)(u(t)^2-1)u(t)dt$$
with $G(t,x)=1/2 (t-x) sign(t-x)$, and with exact solution $u(x)=\tanh (x/\sqrt{2})$. Integrated exact solution we get that

```
f[t_]:=-(1/4) (-Sqrt[2] t + Sqrt[2] Sech[1/Sqrt[2]]^2 - 
   Sqrt[2] t Sech[1/Sqrt[2]]^2 - 2 Tanh[1/Sqrt[2]]);
```

For numerical solution we use Bernoulli wavelets and `GaussianQuadratureWeights[]`. This code produces numerical solution with absolute error $2.26\times 10^{-5}$ with 32 collocation points only:

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"]; \
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"]; 
ue[t_] := Tanh[t/Sqrt[2]]; 
f[t_] := -(1/
   4) (-Sqrt[2] t + Sqrt[2] Sech[1/Sqrt[2]]^2 - 
    Sqrt[2] t Sech[1/Sqrt[2]]^2 - 2 Tanh[1/Sqrt[2]]); 
G[x_, z_] := (1/2) (x - z) Sign[x - z];
n = 4;
M = Sum[1, {j, 0, n, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 1; 
dx = 1/M; A = 0; xl = Table[A + l*dx, {l, 0, M}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, M + 1}]; 
psi1[x_] := Piecewise[{{BernoulliB[2, x], 0 <= x < 1}, {0, True}}]; 
psi2[x_] :=  Piecewise[{{BernoulliB[1, x], 0 <= x < 1}, {0, True}}]; 
psi1jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi1[j*x - k]; 
psi2jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi2[j*x - k]; 
psijk[x_, j_, k_] := (psi1jk[x, j, k] + psi2jk[x, j, k]);


np = 2 M; g = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, 0, 1];
points = g[[All, 1]]; weights = g[[All, 2]];
GuassInt[ff_, z_] := 
  Sum[(ff /. z -> points[[i]])*weights[[i]], {i, np}];
u[t_] := Sum[
    a[j, k]*psijk[t, 2^j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + a0 ; 
int[x_] := GuassInt[G[x, z] (u[z]^2 - 1) u[z], z];
eq = Table[-u[xcol[[i]]] + f[xcol[[i]]] + int[xcol[[i]]] == 0, {i, 
    Length[xcol]}];
varM = Join[{a0}, 
   Flatten[Table[a[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]]; 
sol = FindRoot[eq, Table[{varM[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varM]}]];
unum = Table[ {xcol[[i]], Evaluate[u[xcol[[i]]] /. sol]}, {i, 
    Length[xcol]}];



 (*Absolute error*)  du = Table[{x, Abs[ue[x] - Evaluate[u[x] /. sol]]}, {x, xcol}]
```

Visualization

```
{Show[Plot[ue[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{"Exact"}, LabelStyle -> {Black, 15}], 
     Scaled[{0.2, 0.8}]], AspectRatio -> 1, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[{FontSize -> 15}, Black], 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "u"}, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
  ListPlot[unum, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[PointLegend[{"Numeric"}, LabelStyle -> {Black, 15}], 
     Scaled[{0.2, 0.9}]]]], 
 ListPlot[du, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Row[{"Absolute error. Number of collocation points =", M}]]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: If the integralequation holds especially for `f[x]==0`, the expression `u[x] - NIntegrate[G[x, z] (u[z]^2 - 1) u[z], {z, 0, 1}] /. 
 u -> (Tanh[#/Sqrt[2]] &)` should vanish for all `x` I think. But it doesn't. Any idea?

Comment: @Alex Trounev: many thanks for your answer, but I still have further questions. I need to solve numerically the integral with f[x]=0 and with the interval from -\infinity to +\infinity, because then I want to apply the same method to another integral equation with a different kernel and of which I don't know any exact solution. So, do you think that your code can be adapted to the case f[x]=0 and interval from -infty to +infty (of course by taking something like -a to +a, where a is sufficiently large).

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Hello! I think that the that difference (with f[x]=0) will vanish only when the integral is taken from -infinity to +infinity. I mean that the hyperbolic tangent is an exact solution of the integral with f[x]=0 only when we take the integral from -infinity to +infinity.

Comment: @user92 Thanks,  I checked it, you're right! That means, you should change the integration range in your question too?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: You are right! I am sorry, I didn't specify it....I will change it now. I had put from -10 to 10 meaning some sufficiently large interval. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: @user92 Unit interval is standard for Fredholm integral equation.  Also interval `{t,-Infinity, Infinity}` is not used with numerical methods. Finite interval like `{t,-10,10}`can be mapped to the unit interval without singularity. If we don't know exact solution, and we know kernel, we can solve it even by iterations. In your specific case there is exact solution `y=0`. This is the problem for method of iterations. Why we prefer to use equation in a form with $f\ne 0$.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Did you read my answer? $f\ne 0$ since we used finite interval. If you know some method for infinite interval please publish your answer.

Comment: @AlexTrouney Thanks, I'll try to show my idea in an answer.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Your answer is very interesting. I understand the collocation method as somekind of galerkin method. My question(sorry I'm not very familar with wavelets): Why did you choose basic functions `psijk[t, 2^j, k]` all with slope zero  `Derivative[1, 0, 0][psijk][0, 2^j, k]==0` at `t==0`? If I plot the numeric solution `u[x]/.sol` I see a significant error near `t==0`!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Actually numerical solution defined at collocation points only, and `t=0` it is not collocation point.  Some extrapolation is possible but not with  `psijk[t, 2^j, k]`. The choice of `psijk[t, 2^j, k]` is very special for algorithm to solve integral equation with zero absolute error like on  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226421/high-precision-numerical-solution-of-the-nonlinear-volterra-integral-equation