# Minimization using NMinimize

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions

I have a system of ODEs say

$$x'(t)=2 x(t)-x(t)y(t)-3 x(t) g(t),$$
$$y'(t)= y(t)-2 x(t)y(t)- x(t) g(t)$$

with ICs  $x(0)= 1, y(0)=1/2$, say, for $t_0 \leqslant  t \leqslant t_f$, where $t_0$ and $t_f$ are start and final times.

The function $g(t)$ is a discrete function:
$g(t) = u_i$ for  $t_i<= t <= t_{i+1}$  with  $t_i$  a discretization of the interval  $[t_0,t_f]$,  $t_i= t_0+i h$  with  $h=(t_f-t_0)/N$,  a fixed step size. Note that the parameters $u_i$ are either $0$ or $1$.

The aim is to find the optimal sequence ${u_0, u_1,...,u_{N-1}}$ with $u_i = 0$  or $1$ such that an objective function, say

$$\int_{t_0}^{t_f}[ (x(t)-1)^2+(y(t)-1)^2]dt$$

is minimum.

Any help is very much appreciated. Can try with $N=5$.

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Why not to put $t_0=0$?

Comment: Yes t_0 can be 0.

Answer (score 4):

I think this should do it. First define the piecewise function:

```
g[u_List, tmax_] := Block[{t},
  Function[t,
   Evaluate @ Dot[u,
     Boole[#1 <= t < #2] & @@@
      Partition[Subdivide[0, tmax, Length[u]], 2, 1]
     ]
   ]
  ]
```

`g` is a function that returns a function. For example:

```
g[{1, 0, 1}, 1]
%[0.8]
```

Next, define the equations. I added an extra equation that keeps track of the integral using the variable `int`:

```
Clear[x, y, u, t, int, uvec, npts]
npts = 5;
tmax = 1;
uvec = Array[u, npts];
eqs = {
  x'[t] == 2 x[t] - x[t] y[t] - 3 x[t] g[uvec, tmax][t],
  y'[t] == y[t] - 2 x[t] y[t] - x[t] g[uvec, tmax][t],
  int'[t] == (x[t] - 1)^2 + (y[t] - 1)^2,
  x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1/2, int[0] == 0
  }
```

Solve using `ParametricNDSolveValue`:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  eqs,
  {int[tmax], Function[t, {x[t], y[t]}]},
  {t, 0, tmax},
  uvec
  ]
```

Test if it works for a typical `u` vector:

```
sol[1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

> {0.7955, Function[t$, ...]}

Minimize the solution over the given constraints:

```
min = NMinimize[
  {
   Indexed[sol @@ uvec, 1],
   uvec \[Element] Integers && And @@ Map[# == 0 || # == 1 &, uvec]
   },
  uvec
 ]
```

> {0.7955, {u[1] -> 1, u[2] -> 1, u[3] -> 0, u[4] -> 0, u[5] -> 1}}

Plot the solution:

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[Last[sol @@ uvec /. Last[min]][t]],
 {t, 0, tmax}
]
Plot[
  Evaluate[Last[sol @@ uvec /. Last[min]][t]], {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotLabel -> {uvec /. min[[2]]}
]
```

> [image]

> [image]

Solution for `npts = 8`:

> [image]

## Edit

It should be noted that this approach scales very badly because the discrete nature of the `u[i]` doesn't allow `NMinimize` to use any sort of gradient-based method. This means that it just has to brute-force all `2^npts` possibilities.

Instead, consider something like:

```
min = FindMinimum[
  Evaluate @ {
     Indexed[sol @@ uvec, 1],
     uvec \[Element] Reals && And @@ Map[0 <= # <= 1 &, uvec]
  },
  Evaluate @ Thread[{uvec, 1/2}]
]
```

Comment: (+1) this is a good answer. Also  for `npts=8` it is 1:1 to solution I got with different algorithm without `NDSolve` and `NMinimize`. Can you add picture `Plot[Evaluate[Last[sol @@ uvec /. Last[min]][t]], {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotLabel -> {uvec /. min[[2]]}]` ?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Pictures has been added. It looks like the function `g[t]` can stabilize the `x` coordinate reasonably well, but the `y` coordinate just runs away.

Comment: Thank you! I mean picture with `npts=8` to compare then with my code. Now I try to get solution with `npts=16` to test you code.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Added pictures for 8 control points.

Comment: Thank you! I have added code to compare. Can you run your code with `npts=16`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev No offense, but why can't you run it for yourself? Just copy-paste it into a notebook and run it; I doubt it's going to return anything else on my machine.

Comment: You code is running on my laptop > 3 h with `npst=16`. May be you can handle your code to run faster?

Comment: @AlexTrounev It's to be expected that this becomes inefficient since NMinimize cannot use any gradient-based methods when the `u[i]` are discrete like this. It's just a brute-force search among 2^16 possibilities, which gets expensive fast. It might be better to constrain them as `0 <= u[i] <= 1` instead

Comment: I agree with you, but look at collocation method I have implemented to solve this problem. It handle same $2^{17}=131072$ variants in 1 h and we can decrease this time to several minutes with `Compile`. Then we can compare this to high optimized function like `NMinimize` which not finished yet after 4 h. :)

Comment: Ok! I got solution with your code for `npst=16` after 8 h 27min. It looks nice and not so differ with   `npst=8` in minimum value - 0.783045 and 0.787574 consequently.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be solved with collocation method using Bernoulli wavelets. We don't need to run `NDSolve` and `NMinimize` so it is alternative to that proposed by Sjoerd Smit. Nevertheless we can compare final result for `npts=8`. First we define wavelets, functions and derivatives as follows

```
n = 2;


M = Sum[1, {j, 0, n, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 1; U = Array[u, {M}];
dx = 1/M; A = 0; xl = Table[A + l*dx, {l, 0, M}]; tcol = 
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, M + 1}]; 
psi1[x_] := Piecewise[{{BernoulliB[2, x], 0 <= x < 1}, {0, True}}];
psi2[x_] := Piecewise[{{BernoulliB[1, x], 0 <= x < 1}, {0, True}}];
psi1jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi1[j*x - k];
psi2jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi2[j*x - k];
psijk = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {j, _Integer}, {k, _Integer}}, (psi1jk[x,
        j, k] + psi2jk[x, j, k])/2];
(*intjk=Integrate[psijk[x,j,k],x,Assumptions\[Rule]{j>0,k>0}]*)
psijk1 = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {j, _Integer}, {k, _Integer}}, 
   Piecewise[{{(-k + k^2)/(2*j), 
      j > 0 && k == 0 && 
       1/j - x < 0}, {(1/6)*(-x + 3*k^2*x - 3*j*k*x^2 + j^2*x^3), 
      j > 0 && k == 0 && x > 0 && 
       1/j - x >= 
        0}, {(k - k^3 - j*x + 3*j*k^2*x - 3*j^2*k*x^2 + j^3*x^3)/(6*
         j), j > 0 && k > 0 && k/j - x < 0 && 1/j + k/j - x >= 0}}, 
    0]];
Psi[x_] := 
  Join[{1}, 
   Flatten[Table[psijk[x, 2^j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]];
int1[x_] := 
  Join[{x}, 
   Flatten[Table[
     psijk1[x, 2^j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]];
var1 = Join[{a0}, 
  Flatten[Table[a[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]]; var2 = 
 Join[{b0}, 
  Flatten[Table[b[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]]; var3 = 
 Join[{c0}, Flatten[Table[c[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]];
z1[t_] := var3.Psi[t]; z[t_] := var3.int1[t] + c1;
y1[t_] := var1.Psi[t]; y[t_] := var1.int1[t] + a1; 
x1[t_] := var2.Psi[t]; x[t_] := var2.int1[t] + b1;
```

Second, we define  model to be optimized

```
varM = Join[{a1, b1, c1}, var1, var2, var3]; tf = 1; 
j = 0; 
AbsoluteTiming[Do[j = j + 1; eq = Flatten[Table[{2*x[xcol[[i]]] - 3*u[i]*x[xcol[[i]]] - x1[xcol[[i]]]/tf - x[xcol[[i]]]*y[xcol[[i]]] == 0, 
        (-u[i])*x[xcol[[i]]] + y[xcol[[i]]] - 2*x[xcol[[i]]]*y[xcol[[i]]] - y1[xcol[[i]]]/tf == 0, 
        -z1[xcol[[i]]]/tf + (x[xcol[[i]]] - 1)^2 + (y[xcol[[i]]] - 1)^2 == 0}, {i, Length[xcol]}]]; 
    cons = Join[eq, {x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1/2, z[0] == 0}]; sol[j] = Quiet[FindRoot[cons, Table[{varM[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varM]}]]]; 
    s[j] = z[1] /. sol[j]; uu[j] = U; , {u[1], 0, 1, 1}, {u[2], 0, 1, 1}, {u[3], 0, 1, 1}, {u[4], 0, 1, 1}, {u[5], 0, 1, 1}, {u[6], 0, 1, 1}, 
   {u[7], 0, 1, 1}, {u[8], 0, 1, 1}]]
```

Third, we can fined minimum and plot solution as follows

```
{km, sm} = MinimalBy[Table[{k, s[k]}, {k, 1, j}], Last][[1]]
(*{227, 0.786878}*)
lst1 = Join[{{0, 1}}, 
  Table[{xcol[[i]], x[xcol[[i]]] /. sol[km]}, {i, M}]]; lst2 = 
 Join[{{0, 1/2}}, Table[{xcol[[i]], y[xcol[[i]]] /. sol[km]}, {i, M}]];

ListLinePlot[{lst1, lst2}, PlotLabel -> uu[km], Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, PlotLegends -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

So far so good, we have practically same minimum value `0.786878` compare to solution by Sjoerd Smit of `0.787574`.
Now we put `n=3` in my code that corresponds to `npts = 16`. In this case model to be optimized is

```
    varM = Join[{a1, b1, c1}, var1, var2, var3]; tf = 1; 
j = 0; 
AbsoluteTiming[Do[j = j + 1; eq = Flatten[Table[{2*x[xcol[[i]]] - 3*u[i]*x[xcol[[i]]] - x1[xcol[[i]]]/tf - x[xcol[[i]]]*y[xcol[[i]]] == 0, 
        (-u[i])*x[xcol[[i]]] + y[xcol[[i]]] - 2*x[xcol[[i]]]*y[xcol[[i]]] - y1[xcol[[i]]]/tf == 0, 
        -z1[xcol[[i]]]/tf + (x[xcol[[i]]] - 1)^2 + (y[xcol[[i]]] - 1)^2 == 0}, {i, Length[xcol]}]]; 
    cons = Join[eq, {x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1/2, z[0] == 0}]; sol[j] = Quiet[FindRoot[cons, Table[{varM[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varM]}]]]; 
    s[j] = z[1] /. sol[j]; uu[j] = U; , {u[1], 0, 1, 1}, {u[2], 0, 1, 1}, {u[3], 0, 1, 1}, {u[4], 0, 1, 1}, {u[5], 0, 1, 1}, {u[6], 0, 1, 1}, 
   {u[7], 0, 1, 1}, {u[8], 0, 1, 1}, {u[9], 0, 1, 1}, {u[10], 0, 1, 1}, {u[11], 0, 1, 1}, {u[12], 0, 1, 1}, {u[13], 0, 1, 1}, 
   {u[14], 0, 1, 1}, {u[15], 0, 1, 1}, {u[16], 0, 1, 1}]]
```

With my code we got final result in 26 min at `j=65536`. New result is

```
 {km, sm} = MinimalBy[Table[{k, s[k]}, {k, 1, j}], Last][[1]]

(*Out[]= {63763, 0.782377} *)
```

This result not so differ from above while picture not looks similar

[image: Figure 2]

This code can be optimize with `Compile` and `ParallelDo` as it shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221609/solver-for-covid-19-epidemic-model-with-the-caputo-fractional-derivatives). We also can compare last picture with `NMimimize` (it finished after 8 h 27 min running on my laptop). Final result looks like

```
min = NMinimize[{Indexed[sol @@ uvec, 1], 
        uvec \[Element] Integers && And @@ Map[# == 0 || # == 1 &, uvec]},
        uvec] // AbsoluteTiming
    
Out[]= {30454.7, {0.783045, {u[1] -> 1, u[2] -> 1, u[3] -> 1, 
   u[4] -> 1, u[5] -> 1, u[6] -> 0, u[7] -> 0, u[8] -> 0, u[9] -> 1, 
   u[10] -> 0, u[11] -> 0, u[12] -> 1, u[13] -> 0, u[14] -> 0, 
   u[15] -> 1, u[16] -> 0}}}
```

Now we have difference in vector `U` as well, while minimum value with my code and with `NMinimize` - 0.782377 and 0.783045 consequently. Pictures also are differ but it can be explained by different interpolation method with wavelets and `NDSolve`.
[image: Figure 4]

Comment: Thanks to all for valuable insights. My ultimate goal is to see if Mathematica NMinimize or FindMinimum can deal with a large scale problem where I ultimately want to consider the discritization step from t0 to tf to be fine enough such as dt=10^(-3)  and this will produce 2^(10^3) possibilities. That is HUGE !!!

Comment: Also, I want to comment on Bernoulli wavelets approach. Why specifically such basis functions? Do they have specific approximation property over other basis functions?

Comment: @Moe With wavelets approach  it is possible to make small step size, but with `NMinimize` it is not possible to solve this problem directly since even for `dt=1/16` it takes  8 h 27 min while with wavelets it takes 26 min without optimization. Also it should be algorithm different from that shown above. I am testing Bernoulli wavelets for different problems like this one   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226421/high-precision-numerical-solution-of-the-nonlinear-volterra-integral-equation

Comment: Great! Can these wavelets (or the approach of using them) handle a fine step size say h=0.01 with say t0=0 and tmax=12.? As I mentioned in my previous comment, my ultimate goal to consider the problem of having number of control points as a parameter as well as the final time tmax, in addition to u[i]. So I would have to minimize an cost function with respect to control points t1, t2, t3, ...,tN, (where N is also a parameter) and the u[i], i=1,...,N

Comment: @Moe Problem with unknown $N$ is different from that we discussed here. Also it can be solved with wavelets and with algorithm we need to develop. This new algorithm should by supported  with some theorem about convergence of such solution.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the reply. I understand N should be fixed a priori. On another note, I have been following carefully the code using Bernoulli wavelet methods to understand how it works. To me, it seems it based on approximating the solution x(t) and y(t) as well as their derivatives x'(t) and y'(t) each by linear combination of Bernoulli functions with to be determined coefficients:z1[t_] := var3.Psi[t]; z[t_] := var3.int1[t] + c1;
y1[t_] := var1.Psi[t]; y[t_] := var1.int1[t] + a1; 
x1[t_] := var2.Psi[t]; x[t_] := var2.int1[t] + b1;

Comment: Thanks Alex for the reply. I understand N should be fixed a priori. On another note, I have been following carefully the code using Bernoulli wavelet methods to understand how it works. To me, it seems it based on approximating the solution x(t) and y(t) as well as their derivatives x'(t) and y'(t) each by linear combination of Bernoulli functions with to be determined coefficients:z1[t] := var3.Psi[t]; z[t] := var3.int1[t] + c1;
y1[t] := var1.Psi[t]; y[t] := var1.int1[t] + a1;  x1[t] := var2.Psi[t]; x[t] := var2.int1[t] + b1.

Comment: I figured that x'(t) and y'(t) are approximated by x1[t_] and y1[t_] ==> x(t) and y(t) are approximated by x[t_] and y[t_]. What I don't see it what do z1[t_] and z[t_] represent? I will keep trying to understand the code before I ask any more questions that may seem trivial to you. Many thanks

Comment: @Moe In my code `z` is the same function as `int` in the  Sjoerd Smit code. This is integral to be optimized. In the first version of my code the integral been computed with Gauss approximation. In the current version the new variable  added to compare with  numerical solution by  Sjoerd Smit.