# Problem of step size effectively zero

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I've been trying to solve the next system of differential equations which is very similar to this one in which I also sought help

[Step size is effectively zero](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237117)

$$F^2-G^2+HF'-F''+1=0$$

$$2GF+HG'-G''=0$$

$$2F+H'=0$$

$$HH'+P'-H''=0$$

With boundary conditions

$$F(0)=G(0)=H(0)=P(0)=0$$

$$F(∞)=0, G(∞)=1$$

Again, I turned them into a system of first order ordinary differential equations, $F=x, F'=y, G=z, G'=s, H'=p$ and $P=u$. So I tried the same code that run with the original system, with a few corrections, but it doesn't seem to work with this system, probably because it is unstable too. At t = 3.45 there is a step size effectively zero problem. I also tried with `ParametricNDSolve`, but I really don't know how it works. In the original system I had an idea of the behavior of the solution unlike this case in which I don't, so I assumed P(14) = 0, in an attempt to copy the idea of getting a similar solution and then improve it.

```
odes = {x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == x[t]^2 - z[t]^2 + s[t] y[t] + 1, 
   s'[t] == 2 z[t] x[t] + p[t] s[t], z'[t] == s[t], p'[t] == -2 x[t], 
   u'[t] == 2 x[t] p[t] - 2 y[t]};
bcs = {x[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, p[0] == 0, x[14] == 0, z[14] == 1, 
   u[0] == 0};
vars = {x, y, z, s, p, u};
sol32 = NDSolve[{odes, bcs}, vars, {t, 0, 14}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {s[14] == 0, y[14] == 0, 
       p[14] == 0, x[14] == 0, z[14] == 1, u[14] == 0}}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 6, AccuracyGoal -> 6, WorkingPrecision -> 32];

solMP = NDSolve[{odes, bcs}, vars, {t, 0, 14}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {Through[vars[14]] == 
       Through[vars[14] /. First[sol32]]}}, PrecisionGoal -> 10, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 10]

ListLinePlot[{x, z, p} /. First[sol], PlotLegends -> {F, G, H}]
```

It is the exact same one in the original post but with the equation $u'= 2 x p - 2y$, and $u(14) = 0$.

Comment: Are you looking solution with `NDSolve` only or with any other methods?

Comment: Any method that works will be fine, it is highly unlikely that this system has an analytical solution though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be solved with collocation method using Bernoulli wavelets. First we map interval to the unit interval and define wavelets, functions and derivatives for `vars = {x, y, z, s, p, u}` on the unit domain as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]

n = 4;
M = Sum[1, {j, 0, n, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 1;
dx = 1/M; A = 0; xl = Table[A + l*dx, {l, 0, M}]; tcol = 
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, M + 1}]; 
psi1[x_] := Piecewise[{{BernoulliB[2, x], 0 <= x < 1}, {0, True}}];
psi2[x_] := Piecewise[{{BernoulliB[1, x], 0 <= x < 1}, {0, True}}];
psi1jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi1[j*x - k];
psi2jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi2[j*x - k];
psijk = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {j, _Integer}, {k, _Integer}}, (psi1jk[x,
        j, k] + psi2jk[x, j, k])/2];
(*intjk=Integrate[psijk[x,j,k],x,Assumptions\[Rule]{j>0,k>0}]*)
psijk1 = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {j, _Integer}, {k, _Integer}}, 
   Piecewise[{{(-k + k^2)/(2*j), 
      j > 0 && k == 0 && 
       1/j - x < 0}, {(1/6)*(-x + 3*k^2*x - 3*j*k*x^2 + j^2*x^3), 
      j > 0 && k == 0 && x > 0 && 
       1/j - x >= 
        0}, {(k - k^3 - j*x + 3*j*k^2*x - 3*j^2*k*x^2 + j^3*x^3)/(6*
         j), j > 0 && k > 0 && k/j - x < 0 && 1/j + k/j - x >= 0}}, 
    0]];
Psi[x_] := 
  Join[{1}, 
   Flatten[Table[psijk[x, 2^j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]];
int1[x_] := 
  Join[{x}, 
   Flatten[Table[
     psijk1[x, 2^j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]];
var1 = Join[{a0}, 
  Flatten[Table[a[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]]; var2 = 
 Join[{b0}, 
  Flatten[Table[b[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]]; var3 = 
 Join[{c0}, 
  Flatten[Table[c[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]]; var4 = 
 Join[{d0}, 
  Flatten[Table[d[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]]; var5 = 
 Join[{e0}, 
  Flatten[Table[e[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]]; var6 = 
 Join[{f0}, Flatten[Table[f[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]];
z1[t_] := var3 . Psi[t]; z[t_] := var3 . int1[t] + c1;
y1[t_] := var1 . Psi[t]; y[t_] := var1 . int1[t] + a1; 
x1[t_] := var2 . Psi[t]; x[t_] := var2 . int1[t] + b1;
s1[t_] := var4 . Psi[t]; s[t_] := var4 . int1[t] + d1;
p1[t_] := var5 . Psi[t]; p[t_] := var5 . int1[t] + e1; 
u1[t_] := var6 . Psi[t]; u[t_] := var6 . int1[t] + f1;
```

Second, we define boundary conditions and equations to be optimize

```
L = 14;
    bcs = {x[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, p[0] == 0, x[1] == 0, z[1] == 1, 
       u[0] == 0};
  

  eq = Flatten[Table[{-x1[xcol[[j]]]/L + y[xcol[[j]]], 1 + x[xcol[[j]]]^2 + s[xcol[[j]]]*y[xcol[[j]]] - y1[xcol[[j]]]/L - z[xcol[[j]]]^2, 
      p[xcol[[j]]]*s[xcol[[j]]] - s1[xcol[[j]]]/L + 2*x[xcol[[j]]]*z[xcol[[j]]], s[xcol[[j]]] - z1[xcol[[j]]]/L, 
      -p1[xcol[[j]]]/L - 2*x[xcol[[j]]], -u1[xcol[[j]]]/L + 2*p[xcol[[j]]]*x[xcol[[j]]] - 2*y[xcol[[j]]]}, {j, M}]]; 
varM = Join[{a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1}, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6];
```

Finally we use `NMinimize` to solve this problem

```
sol = NMinimize[{Norm[eq], bcs}, varM]
```

With this `bcs` we have norm of equations of 3.83121*10^-6 and it is not bad. For visualization we use `Plot` so `Compile` complains, it is why we use `Plot` with `Quite`

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t/L], z[t/L], p[t/L]} /. sol[[2]]], {t, 0, 14}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"F", "G", "H"}, Frame -> True] // Quiet
```

[image: Figure 1]

We can improve optimal numerical solution using `FindRoot` as follows

```
sol1 = FindRoot[Join[Table[eq[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eq]}], bcs], 
  Table[{varM[[i]], varM[[i]] /. sol[[2]]}, {i, Length[varM]}], 
  MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

But it produces same plot

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t/L], z[t/L], p[t/L]} /. sol1], {t, 0, 14}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"F", "G", "H"}, Frame -> True] // Quiet
```

[image: Figure 2]

For some implementation of the colocation method with Bernoulli wavelets see my post on this forum

[High precision numerical solution of the nonlinear Volterra integral equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226421/high-precision-numerical-solution-of-the-nonlinear-volterra-integral-equation)

There are also answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240806/minimization-using-nminimize/240882#240882) with application Bernoulli wavelets to optimization problem. Some papers about this method

[A new numerical method for fractional order Volterra integro-differential equations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2090447919301005?via%20%253%20Dihub)

[The Bernoulli wavelets operational matrix of integration and its applications for the solution of linear and nonlinear problems in calculus of variations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0096300318310841)

Comment: Thanks! I would not have been able to come up with that code, pretty interesting that the solution has remained virtually the same. I run the code and plotted P, what I was looking for, too.

Comment: @SebastiánFrades You are welcome! This is more effective method for BVP then  "Shooting" method implemented in `NDSolve`.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I'd really appreciate if could you tell me where to read about collocation method using Bernoulli wavelets, or how to use this method in mathematica because I haven't been able to find much on the internet.

Comment: @SebastiánFrades please, see update to my answer.